# Network available check always return false in Android 8.0

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I am using following code for network available check

```
    public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    int[] networkTypes = {ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE,
            ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI};
    try {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager =
                (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (int networkType : networkTypes) {
            NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (activeNetworkInfo != null &&
                    activeNetworkInfo.getType() == networkType)
                return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Same code working perfectly in all versions. But I face strange issue in Android Oreo 8.0

This method always return **false** in Android 8.0 version even network connect.

Device -  Google Pixel

Note : Don't know its Android version issue or device issue.

Anyone help me out

Comment: try this  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            registerReceiver(new ConnectionCheck(), new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"));
        }

Comment: Could you first add a logging statement to your catch block and try again. Without that it is impossible to know if your problem is because of something an exception would alert you about.

Comment: @Kiskae I forgot this. I will try and update you

Answer (score 0):

### Three steps to solve this issue . Ignore code formatting

1. add permission in project manifest file

> ```
>  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
> ```

2. Create Broadcast receiver for Network status check

   public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   ```
   public static ConnectivityReceiverListener connectivityReceiverListener;

   public NetworkChangeReceiver() {
       super();
   }

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
               .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
       NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
       boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null
               && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

       if (connectivityReceiverListener != null) {
           connectivityReceiverListener.onNetworkConnectionChanged(isConnected);
       }
   }

   public static boolean isConnected() {
       ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) Application.getInstance().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
       NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
       return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
   }

   public interface ConnectivityReceiverListener {
       void onNetworkConnectionChanged(boolean isConnected);
   }
   ```

   }
3. create static method and use it anywhere in application

> public static boolean isOnline()   {
>           return NetworkChangeReceiver.isConnected();  }